# OpenCV Parallel for implementation issue

Tags: opencv, c++11, image-processing

I want to apply `tanh` function on each element of OpenCV Matrix. Vaniall implementation using nested for loops gives correct results.

```
    Mat P(Size(3,3),CV_64FC1,Scalar(2));
    Mat P1 = P.clone();
    for( int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; ++i )
    {
        for( int j = 0 ; j < 3 ; ++j )
        {
            P1.at<double>(i,j) = tanh(P1.at<double>(i,j)) ;
        }
    }
    cout<<P1<<endl;
```

Outputs correctly :

```
 [0.9640, 0.9640, 0.9640;
   0.9640, 0.9640, 0.9640;
 0.9640, 0.9640, 0.9640]
```

The Parallel loop implementation using as per guidelines presented [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/22115/best-way-to-apply-a-function-to-each-element-of-mat/).

```
class Parallel_pixel_opencv : public ParallelLoopBody
{
private:
    uchar *p ;
public:
    Parallel_pixel_opencv(uchar* ptr ) : p(ptr) {}

    virtual void operator()( const Range &r ) const
    {
        for ( register int i = r.start; i != r.end; ++i)
        {
            p[i] = (uchar)tanh( p[i] )  ;
        }
    }
}; 
int main()
{

    Mat P(Size(3,3),CV_64FC1,Scalar(2));
    Mat P2 = P.clone();
    uchar* p3 = P2.data ;
    parallel_for_( Range(0,3*3) , Parallel_pixel_opencv(p3)) ;
    cout<<P2<<endl; 
}
```

Outputs

```
[7.2911227e-304, 2, 2;
  2, 2, 2;
  2, 2, 2]
```

I am unable to track down the implementation issue here.

Comment: You appear to be doing `tanh(uchar*)` in one and `tanh(double*)` in the other.

Comment: @MarkSetchell that's the first thing I noticed, yet it might sense since they are pixels, and is still unclear why 2 would be the result, vs 1 or 0

Answer (score 0):

Using char* pointer instead of double* pointer should explain the wrong result.

But:

(1) I don't believe that a parallel operation for a 3x3 Matrix improves performance.

(2) cv::Mat has a forEach method that can be used with C++11 lambdas. That should be simpler. See https://www.learnopencv.com/parallel-pixel-access-in-opencv-using-foreach/ for an example.